# Vuejs add new values to existing array

Tags: arrays, vue.js, slice

I have a post section which includes the comments section similarly to fb

Here is my array structure:
[image]

Now I have a comment box section which will replace the first comment with the new one. I can successfully update the new comment in the database but I just cannot re-fetch the whole component just to show a single comment.

I have tried with .push method but it's not reactive and I am not able to understand the slice method, I just simply want to have some direction.

```
  let newComment = {
    text: "offline comment",
  };

  const test = this.Fitness_Posts[0].postComments.splice(0,1, newComment);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
const post = this.Fitness_Posts[0];
post.postComments = [...post.postComments, newComment];
```

it basically spreads all of your current `postComments` into a new array which also includes `newComment` and replacing the `postComments` array with the new one

Comment: But it's not reactive the v-for loop defined in the template section isn't changing.
I even tried with `this.$set(this.posts[0].postComments, 1, newComment);` but no change

Comment: I realized that there was another nested object inside the postComments which i rendered on html but forgot to add in the newComment thank you so much for your help!